# comparación en PHP de string con int

Tags: php

Llevo un rato peleando con un if que me da false constantemente.

Estoy comparando una variable que tiene un int con otra que es un string.

He casteado el int a string y viceversa. He probado con funciones como 'strnatcasecmp(string1, string2) y nada...

ya no sé qué más hacer, seguramente tenga que ver con que utilizo javascript dentro del mismo php para pedir uno de los datos, o no... ni idea...

Pego el código a ver si encontráis el fallo:

```
$codigo = random_int(111111, 999999);

function comprobarCodigo($bool, $codigo){
    echo "<script>var code = prompt('...', 'Introduce el código');</script>";
    $code = "<script>document.write(code)</script>";

    if ($codigo == $code) {
        enviarDatos();
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('El código introducido es incorrecto. Por favor, vuelve a intentarlo.');</script>";
        comprobarCodigo($bool, $codigo);
    }
```

Gracias.

Comment: Veo varios motivos por los que ese condicional IF siempre es falso, si te das cuenta, estas comparando este String: "<script>document.write(code)</script>" con un numero aleatorio. No estas comparando el resultado del código JS sino el texto escrito en JS. ¿Que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente?

Comment: Gracias! ya veo por dónde va el problema, no me había dado cuenta de eso...

Lo que pretendo es igualar un código aleatorio, "$codigo" (que se envía por correo electrónico al usuario para comprobar que el correo es válido antes de guardar los datos del usuario en la base de datos), con la variable "$code" (que la recojo mediante javascript con un prompt, no sé si hay forma de hacer algo parecido con PHP, pero lo busqué y no lo encontré).

Comment: Bueno, he intentado esto:

$codeRefinado = substr($code, 23, 6);

Pero al compararlo con esa nueva cadena, tenía un "echo" para ver lo que iba saliendo y me ha dado: 

code)<

Sin embargo antes, usando $code, si me mostraba al número. El problema es que aun imprimiéndose iguales en pantalla, incluso cuando los parseo, no me da true.